# How to Catch Server Sent events (SSE) through proxy servlet

Tags: java, servlets, server-sent-events

we maintain 2 applications ( application1 runs in glassfish server which have proxyservlet, application2 runs with the jetty server in same machines). My UI code make request---> app1(proxyservlet) --> app2 and response coming back to UI but Application2 uses SSE(Server sent events). My proxyservlet not able to catch the events so not able to forward that events to UI.

proxyservlet code is https://github.com/mitre/HTTP-Proxy-Servlet

Please anyone give suggestions how to get SSE events through servlet to UI